# Product of non-trivial group subsets is not (necessarily) a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a non-trivial group then the product of its non-empty subsets does not (necessarily) define a group structure on the set $\wp \left( G \right)-\left\{ \varnothing  \right\}$.
So far, I've proven that this product defines a monoid structure on the set $\wp \left( G \right)-\left\{ \varnothing  \right\}$. Obviously, there must be an element within $\wp \left( G \right)-\left\{ \varnothing  \right\}$  which has no inverse element. Any suggestion how to construct a non-trivial group $G$ with such a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $G$ is non-trivial, it is a non-identity element of $\mathcal{P}(G) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ (the identity in $\mathcal{P}(G) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ is $\{e\}$). But $G$ is idempotent in $\mathcal{P}(G) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$, $G \cdot  G = G$, as $x \cdot y \in G, \forall x, y \in G$. Thus, $G$ can't have an inverse in $\mathcal{P}(G) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: So the only idempotent in a group is the identity.  Ok.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yes indeed. In fact, every non-trivial subgroup of $G$ fails to have an inverse for this reason.

Comment: What about a non-trivial group $G=\left\{ e,x,y,... \right\}$ with the following property: $\forall x\in G\forall y\in G\left( xy=e \right)$?

Comment: @Gabrielė there is no non-trivial group satisfiying the property. Because $x^2 = e$ and $x^3 = e$ i.e. $x^3 = x^2$. Cancelling $x^2$ gives $x = e$.

Comment: Thanks, you've saved a lot of time for me!

Comment: @Gabrielė glad to be of help.